# Do you have disadvantage when attacking a small or tiny creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, attack, creature-size

**Background**:   I'm still somewhat fairly new to Dming, but I overall have a decent understanding of a majority of the rules and how gameplay works. During my last session a player mentioned that as my large monster went to attacked a tiny PC, the monster would have a disadvantage. I had never heard of this rule but because it was just a quick one-shot session I allowed this to be a rule for the evening.

**Question**: My question, however, is I'd like to know if this is an actual rule. When attacking a **Small** or **Tiny** creature, does the attacking creature have a disadvantage?

Answer (score 8):

#### No. It's not the size that matters ...

The armor class of any creature will reflect how difficult it is to hit.  Where the rules identify a specific source of disadvantage (for example, a Sprite when *invisible* will cause disadvantage<sup>1</sup> on an attack against it) the general case has no direct linkage between size and advantage/disadvantage in hitting such a creature.

> During my last session a player mentioned that as my large monster went to attacked a tiny PC, the monster would have a disadvantage

That may have been a rule from a previous edition, but isn't a general rule in this edition.  There are some creatures, however, who can benefit from cover due to their small size.

For example, the Lightfoot Halfling (SRD p. 5 / PHB) has a specific racial feature unique to that character race:

> **Naturally Stealthy**. You can attempt to hide even when you are obscured
>   only by a creature that is at least one size larger than you.

Being hidden/obscured will negatively influence attack attempts against that creature.  That's a case for "specific over general" making that creature more difficult to hit sometimes.

---

<sup>1</sup>  The sprites invisibility and the "unseen attackers and targets" rules combine in this case.

> *Invisibility.* The sprite magically turns invisible until it attacks
>   or casts a spell, or until its concentration ends (as if concentrating
>   on a spell). Any equipment the sprite wears or carries is invisible
>   with it. (SRD, Sprite, description).

**Unseen Attackers and Targets**

> Combatants often try to escape their foes’ notice by hiding, casting the invisibility spell, or lurking in darkness.  When you attack a target that you can’t see, you have disadvantage on the attack roll (PHB)

Comment: Great, thank you! I felt like this wasn't an actual rule, but because at the time I wasn't sure I decided to allow it. But again thank you, that clears up so much.